# How to record code + emulator in vs code on windows

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, record

When i am recording the screen via win+alt+R in vs code it is only recording the emulator instead of recording whole screen (code +emulator)
Please suggest something

Comment: you can try obs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recording feature in *Game Tools* will only record one window only at a time, use other third party tool to record extensively.